# How to integrate SSL certificates to the cacerts file in /jre/security folder?

Tags: java, linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

Recently our server got upgraded to SHA-256 based SSL certificate. And from then we are facing `javax.naming.CommunicationException` . In order to resolve this issue i need to add/append a set of Certificate Chain into CACERTS file under the path `/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security` of our server.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764122/how-to-integrate-wsdl-certificates-to-the-cacerts-file-in-jdk-jre-security-folde) of SO which explains the steps to achieve this through a program. Can any one suggest how to add these certificate chains into the cacerts file through linux commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linux command prompt issue the command:

/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/keytool -import -alias <> -file <> -keystore cacerts

That command uses the Java keystore tool to import the new cert file into the existing cacerts file.  The <> is whatever you want to call the cert.  The <> is the actual file you want imported.

If you are prompted for a password, the default keystore password is 'changeit'.

Repeat for each new cert file you want added.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `keytool` utility from the Java distribution, in your case it should be under /usr/lib/jvm/bin directory.

```
keytool -importcert -file your_cert_file_here \
    -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```